# how to call an apex method automatically when a vf page loads ie, how to achieve <aura:handler> or connectedCallback() in vf?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Vf code:

```
<apex:page controller='autocall'>
    <div align='center'>
        {!msg}
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Apex code:

```
public class autocall
{
    public string msg {get;set;}
    public void callme()
    {
        msg='hello world';
    }
}
```

so, how do I call 'autocall()' method automatically when above vf page loads.
please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the apex method on load via [`apex:page`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)'s `action` attribute:

> The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server.
> Use expression language to reference an action method. For example,
> action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the
> controller. If an action isn’t specified, the page loads as usual.
>
> Important: Do not use this action for initialization or DML.

```html
<apex:page controller='autocall' action='{!callme}'>
    <div align='center'>
        {!msg}
    </div>
</apex:page>
```